# Easiest/clearest way to read formatted data in C++

Tags: c++, scanf

I'm reading in a file of space/newline delimited numbers. After trying stringstreams and ifstreams, it appears C++ hasn't improved much on fopen and fscanf for this simple task in terms of simplicity, readability, or efficiency.

What about robustness?  Since I check that fscanf returned the number of items I expect, this doesn't seem like an issue. The only benefit I can think of is stringstream's giving you more options to handle a failure.

Here is a quick example using fscanf:

```cpp
FILE * pFile;
pFile = fopen ("my_file.txt","r");
if( pFile == NULL ) return -1;

double x,y,z;
int items_read;
while( true )
{
    items_read = fscanf( pFile, "%lf %lf %lf", x, y, z );
    if( items_read < 3 ) break;  // Checks for EOF (which is -1) or reading 1-2 numbers

    std::cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << "\n";
}
```

**NOTE**: for extra security, could replace fopen/fscanf with fopen_s/fscanf_s in Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you want these read in a trio of `double` values per-line? or just three at a time, with no accounting for how many are present per line? Is there other data besides these that you're interested in sucking out of the file?

Comment: There is no such functions, as `fopen_s/fscanf_s` in standard C & C++.  The iostreams are type safe. (In your code you use %f for double, and that's an error already).

Comment: why not use stringstream?

Comment: @Lol4t0, good catches. I was about to say how compiler-checking type-safety wasn't that significant to me until you commented on my "type typo"!

Comment: @cf16, my question is, why bother in this case?

Comment: @WhozCraig, the format is known. So there may be other types in the file, but I know exactly the number and type per line.

Comment: @tcdaniel so are you happy with stringstream?

Comment: If you use `std::fstream f` instead of `pfile`, you could simply do `while(f >> x >> y >> z)` and it will exit the loop when there is an error of some sort (or end of file, which technically isn't an error, more an information). It gives as much error handling as your `fscanf` (well, aside from telling you where in the sequence it went wrong, but it's really really useful to know if it's number of inputs on a given line was 1 or 2, when you expect three).

Comment: @cf16,I like `stringstream`'s in general, but it seems more tedious for reading formatted data. So I'm looking for pros/cons I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience neither C nor C++ offer you "robust input that tolerates idiot users".

It is adequate for "well formed input where it's OK to say 'something wrong in your input, please fix it'...", but not for robust situations where you need to check everything carefully (e.g. someone putting two instead of three numbers on a line, so the whole rest of the data is happily acceped, but now all your `z` values are actually `x` values, and everything else is "shifted one").

In that case, you do need to write some functions that do the appropriate checking by reading a line, checking that it can fetch three numbers out of that line - or something like that. You may well find that using `stringstream` or something  similar is adequate for checking that there are three valid numbers on the line, but just using `f >> x >> y >> z;` will obviously lead to the next line being used to satisfy whatever is missing on this line.

Comment: Agreed - and I mentioned error handling as the main argument for `stringstream`'s

Comment: exactly, crazy question: build me a program that do everything. there are always some assumptions, limitations